# how to realise this function?

Tags: ros, python, topic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

two nodes(TO and TS) conmunication by service and topic,how to realise this :

```
   TO                     TS
      --------requst----->         #this is a service ,TO as client,TS as server
      <-------response----


      <-------requst------         #another service,TS as client,TO as server
      -------response---->


      -------topic-------->       # TO as publisher,TS as subscriber
```

here,two nodes communicate during a time,they run in order, I have no idea to edit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35579/how-to-realise-this-function?/) by [malong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2520/malong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-03

Post score: -6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-06-04**:
...I don't understand which part of this is your question.

**Comment by [malong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2520/malong/) on 2012-06-04**:
nodes communicate in different.for example,when this service run over,the node judge if will run the next service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please read the [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) on ros.org.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5